# Can not import @openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol & @openzeppelin/contracts/utils/introspection/ERC165Storage.sol

Tags: go-ethereum

I want to run this code but I get an error.
How do I get it to work?

https://github.com/ERC725Alliance/ERC725/blob/master/implementations/contracts/ERC725/ERC725Y.sol

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to ERC725 root directory and do `npm install` because your error shows that  openzeppelin files are not found so most probably you forgot to install dependencies.

Comment: then try to compile ERC725Y.sol from where it is located not by giving its path.

Comment: npm install done.add picture, please check it